# Module `child_process` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: react-native, npm, google-api

Add to react-native project googleapis (https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) package and after that build is failed with error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `child_process` from `C:\Users\Artem\Documents\signin\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js`: Module `child_process` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

Instead of this `child_process` can be `stream`, `fs`.

Clear npm cache, delete node_modules folder and reinstall all packages don't help me.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "41.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.4",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: I find this answer.
"you can't use packages made for backend. React-native is frontend/web"